# I cannot get my Razor Pages to display in my ASP.NET 5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, .net-5

I'm new to Razor architecture and ASP.NET Core so my apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

I have a new web application written in the newest .NET Core framework, .NET 5.0. I have a pg folder with two Razor Pages, Contact.cshtml and Index.cshtml. I have copied code from other guides into my Startup.cs file to try and get my pages to display but I have gotten nothing but 404 errors so far. Here are the ConfigureServices and Configure methods in my Startup class.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/pg/Index", "");
        });
        // ----------------------------------------------          
        services.AddMvc();

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1500);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
            {
                context.Request.Path = "/pg/Index";
                await next();
            }
        });
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=pg}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

On starting my application I have not been able to display either of my pages. I've tried https://localhost:44328/, https://localhost:44328/pg/Index and https://localhost:44328/pg/Index.cshtml and I just get back "No webpage was found for the web address."

EDIT: Here's my Solution Explorer: [image: Solution Explorer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#create-a-razor-pages-project):

> The runtime looks for Razor Pages files in the Pages folder by default.

If you do not want to change the razor pages folder, add the following code to your Startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(opt => {
    opt.RootDirectory = "/pg";
});
```

Besides, remember to add razor pages endpoint:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=pg}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: TIL the compiler will discover all `.cshtml` files and compile them into your assembly. Adding attributes with their original path. But only those in the `RootDirectory` will be mapped as end points.

Comment: Finally got it! I had to remove the "pg" folder and replace it with "Pages" and then added the endpoint.

Answer (score 4):

You need to [add Razor page endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/):

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        ...
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
```

Your special case for 404 might need to move lower down as well; whether it’s going to be a 404 isn’t established yet where you have it.

Comment: I have made those changes but still am unable to retrieve a page.

Comment: It’s difficult to suggest without seeing your whole project, but take a look at the link - it explains it all quite clearly. Regarding no controllers - you can use just Razor pages without controllers.  Your pages - by convention - go into a Pages folder.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to illustrate your problem using your configurations. And it is working fine for me. Maybe your folder structure is bad or you have not added the required controller.

Since you are using MVC you need to put the `index.razor` file in the Views folder. This is how the folder structure should look like -

[image]

Comment: I was under the impression that by using Razor's Model-View-ViewModel architecture, I would not need controllers. My pg folder is at parent level. I do not have a Views or Controllers folder.

Comment: Yea, at first I tried without a controller and put the `index.cshtml` direct into the pages folder and got the 404.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a folder named **[Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#examine-the-project-files)** , and add all razor pages inside that Pages folder.

In startup.cs under configure method add below code

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
   ..
   endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```